# How access inner of inner property when using Criteria in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class called `Patient` that has a reference to `PatientBasic` class. Like this

```
public class Patient{
       PatientBasic patientBasicInfo;
}

public PatientBasic{
       String firstName;
       ....
}
```

I want to make a Criteria in Hibernate like this:

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Patient.class, "patient");
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("patient.patientBasicInfo.firstName", filter+"%")); //Throws exception
```

But this throws an exception. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for an alias in this simple case:

```
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Patient.class);
    criteria.createCriteria("patientBasicInfo")
                .add(Restrictions.ilike("firstName", filter+"%"));
    List<Patient> patients = criteria.list();
```

Comment: I have some other criterias on the basic criteria too. I tried it and it gives me HTTP Status 500 - Transaction not successfully started

Comment: Update the question with all you have. But it seems the exception is not from the criteria query.

Comment: My bad. Really sorry. I didn't start the transaction. Thanks for help.